# android restringe envio masivos de sms

Tags: android, sms

Hola comunidad de programadores, estoy realizando una app de envió masivo de sms en segundo plano, pero al parecer android me limita el envió, por ejemplo: necesito enviar 50 sms, se envían los 30 primeros luego aparece una notificacion en la pantalla para autorizar (de manera manual) el envio  de cada uno de los restantes 20 sms. No estoy seguro si depende del dispositivo, del sistema operativo o lo que mas me temo "del proveedor de telefonia movil".

Comment: El operador desde luego tiene un limite por segundo

Comment: Spidvm, e probado haciendo un delay de 2 segundos entre mensaje, pero igual llegado al mensaje 30 aparace las notificaciones con el siguente mensaje: "**miApp**  esta enviando un gran numero de mensajes SMS. ¿quieres permitir que esta aplicacion siga enviando mensajes?"

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías usar algún servicio externo de envío de correos masivos. Da una vuelta x internet, seguro que hay alguno gratuito con su propia API para manejar este tipo de tareas...

Comment: ENtomnces quien te pone problemas es tu App, no el operador

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar un thread, yo lo hice y ya no me molesto ese mensaje
En mi caso logre que funcionara enviar 10 y hacer una pausa de 20 segundos

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int contador = 0;
                    int contAux = 0;
                    while (datos.next()) {
                        int total = datos.getInt(5);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MensajeAbonados.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MensajeAbonados.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_SEND_SMS);
                        } else {
                            //do send or read sms
                            String strPhone = datos.getString(1);
                            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            String mensaje = txtMensaje.getText().toString();
                            sms.sendTextMessage("+52"+strPhone, null, mensaje, null, null);
                            contador++;
                            contAux++;
                            toastContador("Enviados " + contador + " de " + total);
                            if (contAux == 10  ) {//NUmero de mensajes para iniciar pausa
                                contAux = 0;
                                Thread.sleep(20000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(contador > 0)
                        progress(pd, "Se enviaron " + contador + " mensajes.");
                    else
                        progress(pd, "No hay mensajes para enviar.");
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    Log.e("SQLError", se.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```